# Bytea to actual text value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, file, bytea

I have a table to store file information in postgresql.

```
select id,filestream,name from Table_file_info
```

[image]

Here `filestream` is `bytea` datatype. How to get bytea data into actual text (content of my file) in postgresql.

I tried with below query:

```
select encode(filestream, 'escape')::text as name from Table_file_info
```

but i am getting as below

```
ICAgICAgICAgc2FkZnNhZGZhZCBzZGRkZGRkZGRkIFRlc3R0dA==
```

actual content of my file is:          **sadfsadfad sddddddddd Testtt** 
[image]

Comment: Use `convert_from(filestream, 'utf-8')` assuming your text is utf-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like base64.  Meaning your file was first converted to base64, then converted to bytea (which is kind of pointless since base64 is already text)

```
select encode(decode(encode(filestream,'escape'),'base64'),'escape') from Table_file_info;
```